# How to integrate Mobile Native application (as a client) with OAuth2

Tags: java, android, ios, oauth-2.0

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with the development of Mobile Native app. I had implemented my own OAuth2 server in the grant type `Authorization Code`. How can I consume it in the `Mobile Native App`?Any client library for IOS or Android? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a blog post a while back about how to do this in ios, if that's helpful: https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/implementing-an-oauth2-login-flow-in-wkwebview-de74e23fe9ee

Comment: @NicholasSolter Thanks for your post, Could you share the full example code with me? Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have any generic example code handy. I will try to write something up, but I won't have time before next week.